# dg-projective complex and module category.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, triangulated-categories, derived-categories

If R is a ring.then the complex $D^.$ of R-modules is called dg-projective complex if Hom complex $Hom^.(D^.,A^.)$ is acyclic for arbitrary acyclic complex $A^.$ of R modules.this   is equivalent to $Hom_{K(R-Mod)}(D^.,A^.)=0$for arbitrary acyclic complex $A^.$ of R modules.

> **My Question**:if $Hom_{K(R-Mod)}(D^.,A^.)=0$ for arbitrary acyclic complex $A^.$ of finite generated R modules.Is $D^.$ dg-projective complex?

when I think about this question,I also find a question.

> if $A$ is abelian category with direct limit,is homotopy category $K(A)$ has direct limit?

thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know if your complexes are bounded or not but, I think one can reduce to the case of bounded complexes using truncations (show that a given complex is the direct limit of its truncations). For a bounded complex, it seems reasonable to be able to show: a bounded complex is the direct limit of its finitely generated subcomplexes. If $D$ is a ``finitely presented" object (probably more appropriate to say a compact object), then I think it will be equivalent.

Comment: @Eoin arbitrary complex.of course l,bound above projective complex is dg-projective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $D^.=\mathbb{Q}$, considered as a complex concentrated in degree zero. $\text{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Q},X)=0$ for any finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module $X$, and so $\text{Hom}_{K(\mathbb{Z}-\text{Mod}))}(\mathbb{Q},A^.)=0$ is zero (and so acyclic) for *all* complexes $A^.$ (and in particular acyclic ones) of finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.

Comment: thanks.if $D^.\in K(R-mod)$,is there any counterexample?It seems that $K(A)$ doesn't have direct limit if $A$ has direct limit.

Comment: @Sky By $R$-$\text{mod}$ you mean the category of finitely generated (or presented?) $R$-modules? I don't immediately see a counterexample or proof, but I'll think about it.

Comment: @Sky  Most triangulated categories won't have arbitrary direct limits (though I don't know a precise description of those that do). Since coproducts are a special case of direct limits, you would at least need coproducts. If $X$ is the direct limit of a direct system $\{X_i\}$ then the natural map $\bigoplus_iX_i\to X$ is an epimorphism, and all epimorphisms split in a triangulated category, so $X$ must be a direct summand of $\bigoplus_iX_i$.

Comment: finite generated R-module.Thank you.

Comment: So perfect observation!

Comment: if $i:K(R-mod)\rightarrow K(R-Mod)$,The counterexample can show that $i$ doesn't sent dg-projective to dg-projective.This seems interesting.